# Redshift connection refused with error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I followed the steps on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html
to connect to my newly created Redshift instance using SQL Workbench/J.

I faced the following error:
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP  connections.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sign-in into AWS Console
2. Search in AWS console for 'Security groups' - You will get 'Security groups (ECS feature)'
3. Select Inbound rules tab < select edit inbound rules (Add Rule: Type=Redshift,
   Source=MyIP. (auto-fill), Save it.)
4. Also In Redshift- Open your
   Cluster < Actions < Modify publically accessible setting < Enable <
   Save Changes

Connect Redshift with SQLWorkbench/J. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add you IP range to the security group for your cluster.

### In the AWS Redshift console:

- Click Security at the left
- Then tick the 'default' group (unless you used another name)
- Then select 'CIDR/IP' in the control at the bottom
- The add your IP in the 'CIDR/IP to Authorize' box

You should now be able to access your cluster.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you have followed all the steps, it should work provided your ip has access to the cluster.

Also, you can try Aginity for Redshift (some AWS engineers recommended this for us), its really good and you do not need any configuration apart from entering the URL of the cluster and login credentials.

http://www.aginity.com/workbench/redshift/